# How to create simple, text output in the shiny in this case?

Tags: r, shiny, prediction, dashboard

I have a little problem with Shiny and general how to create the output.
In the another sheet I've created the prediction model under name "regressor".
I'm using it on the data with columns (Stan, Nominal..PLN., Waga..g., Naklad, Data) - just like inputs below.

What I want to have here is that: I would like to collect input from user on the Dashboard(created probably correctly in the code below).
Then, I would like to create a dataframe from that inputs and to process it through the existing model, like below,

```
y_pred = predict(regressor, newdata=choice)
```

Output should be simple.
That model should give me a value, and I want to have this value printed as an output in the Dashboard.

Unfortunately I don't know how to do that.

I have an another question here. Do I need to load a files and tranform it here in the shiny sheet, or if variables are already in the memory, because they have been processed in the another sheet, it should work here too?

I' ll be REALLY grateful for any help!!

```
library(shiny)



#---- UI -----

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("Motyw",
              "Jaka moneta?",
              c("Boleslaw Chrobry" = "Boleslaw Chrobry"
              ),
              #selected,
              multiple = FALSE,
              selectize = TRUE
              #width,
  ),
  sliderInput("Stan", "Zaznacz stan monety w skali 1-38. 
               1 - najgorszy stan
               38 - stan idealny", value = 1, min = 1, max = 38),
  dateInput("date", "Wpisz dzien sprzedazy monety",   value = NULL, min = NULL, max = NULL),
  selectInput("Nominal",
              "Jaki nominal ma ta moneta",
              c("10" = 10,
                "25" = 25
              ),
              #selected,
              multiple = FALSE,
              selectize = TRUE
              #width,
  ),
  selectInput("Rok", "Rok monety", 1925),
  selectInput("Naklad",
              "Jaki byl naklad monety?",
              c("52350" = 52350
              ),
              #selected,
              multiple = FALSE,
              selectize = TRUE
              #width,
  ),
  selectInput("Rok", "Rok monety", 1925),
  selectInput("Waga",
              "Jaka jest waga w [g] monety?",
              c("3" = 3,
                "6" = 6
              ),
              #selected,
              multiple = FALSE,
              selectize = TRUE
              #width,
  ),


  textInput("wyrzucona", "Wartosc monety to: ")
  
)




#---- SERVER LOGICS -----

  
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  #creating dataframe
  choice <- reactive({
    data.frame(input$Stan,input$Cena,input$Data,input$Nominal,input$Rok,input$Motyw,input$Naklad,input$Waga)
    })
  #changing names of columns
  #names(choice) <- c('Stan', 'Cena', 'Data', 'Nominal..PLN.', 'Rok', 'Motyw', 'Naklad', 'Waga..g.')
  #creating prediction
  wyrzucona <- reactive({y_pred = predict(regressor, newdata=choice)
  })

  observe({
    addtext <- paste("Wartosc twojej monety to: ")
    updateTextInput(session, "wyrzucona", value=addtext)
  })
}
    





#---- CALL APP ----
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: You don't have any outputs in your code anywhere. See the [shiny tutorials and support pages](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/basics.html) for the basic pieces of the shiny app you need.

Comment: Thank you phalteman for this link! Today I'm gonna learn from it and try to implement outputs.
Have a great day!